# Java RMI InitialContext: Equivalent of LocateRegistry.createRegistry(int)?

Tags: java, registry, rmi, initial-context

I am trying to some pretty basic RMI:

```
//   Context namingContext = new InitialContext();
         Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(9999);
         for ( int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++ ) {
            int id = objs[i].getID();
//            namingContext.bind( "rmi:CustomObj" + id , objs[i] );
            reg.bind( "CustomObj" + id , objs[i] );
         }
```

That works without a hitch, but for future purposes, I need to use `InitialContext`.

```
         Context namingContext = new InitialContext();
         for ( int i = 0; i < objs.length; i++ ) {
            int id = objs[i].getID();
             namingContext.bind( "rmi:CustomObj" + id , objs[i] );
         }
```

But I cannot get this to work. I have started `rmiregistry` from the command line. Is there an equivalent of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(int)`? Or some other way to start the RMI registry / registry used by `InitialContext` from inside my class? (Instead of the command line)

---

Stack trace:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bguiz.scratch.network.eg.Student]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:126)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:208)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
        at bguiz.scratch.RMITest.main(RMITest.java:29)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bguiz.scratch.CustomObj
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
        ....(truncated)
```

---

EDIT: I will delete my own question in a couple of days, as there seems to be no answer to this (I haven't been able to figure it out myself). Last call for any biters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tinkering, I've solved the problem. FYI, here's what it was:

The `ClassNotFoundException` is getting thrown because of RMI registry has its own classpath. It doesn't matter that the class containing the `InitialContext` has the custom objects on its classpath - The RMI registry must be initialised such that the custom objects are on *its classpath as well*.

To do this set the `classpath` environment value on the comman line prior to starting `rmiregistry`. If this classpath contains the custom object's class, the `ClassNotFoundException` is not thrown, and subsequently `ServerException` and `CommunicationException' are avoided.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(int)`?

No.

> Or some other way to start the RMI registry / registry used by InitialContext from inside my class?

Only `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()`.

I'm almost sure you need to specify the hostname in the URL. What exception & error message are you getting?

Comment: @EJP I've added the stack trace to my question. Also, this class will run on the server - so no need to specify the URL (it will be local host). The client needs to specify the URL, and since I'm sandboxing in the same machine, it specifies`"rmi://localhost:1099/"`, however I haven't got that far yet, as this class fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bguiz.scratch.network.eg.Student caused by
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bguiz.scratch.CustomObj
```

Check if this class is available ?

Comment: Yes, it most definitely is - it's one of the first things that I checked. In fact the array `objs[]` is an array of `CustomObj`s, which is used by the very same class. I have also verified that it is on the classpath.